# Tkinter menu copy/paste/cut option

Tags: python, tkinter

I have coded in that when you right click you get a menu With copy/cut/paste after some googeling, but i havent found anything about a dropdown menu With copy/cut/paste...
What i got:

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
Edit.add_command(label="Copy")
Edit.add_command(label="Paste")
Edit.add_command(label="Cut")
bar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=Edit)
mainloop()
```

Notes:
I am coding in Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a menubar,

`mymenu = Menu(master)`

create the Edit menu,

`editmenu = Menu(mymenu, tearoff=0) # editmenu is now a child of mymenu`

add your menu options with labels and commands,

```
editmenu.add_command(label='Cut', command=cut) # 'cut' is a cut function you wrote
editmenu.add_command(label='Copy', command=copy) # need a copy function too
editmenu.add_command(label='Paste', command=paste) # paste function
```

then add that Edit menu to the menubar,

`mymenu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=editmenu)`

then add the menubar to the master tk object:

`master.config(menu=mymenu)`

Then a menubar will appear at the top of the window when you run the program. Make sure you define the `cut`, `copy`, and `paste` functions, or you'll get an error. You can use `print` as a placeholder if you want.